# Change Link To value on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm trying to implement a login page for my app.
When the login button is clicked, a fetch is called and tries to login with the user's info.
If the login succeeds, login button's  value updates to be the homepage, else it changes back to the login page address.
Any idea on how to make it work?
I tried `<Link to={redirect?"/home":"/"}>` but it didn't do anything, and I also tried using a state prop which holds the link value but still had problems with it.
Button code:

```
<Link to={redirect?"/home":"/"}>
    <Button
        onClick={submit}
        variant="primary"
        size="lg"
        className="btn-lg"
        type="submit"
    >
        Login
    </Button>
</Link>
```

submit (login) code:

```
const submit = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:2718/user/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(form),
            credentials: 'include',
        });
        if (res.status !== 200) {
            console.log("Error while trying to sign in");
            redirect = false;
        } else {
            console.log("ggoood");
            redirect = true;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        redirect = false;
    }
};
```

*The redirect variable is just a Boolean variable

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: I am not sure how your code is structured, or what is the role of the `redirect` variable. You may need to post some more code. One suggestion I can think of is this
`{redirect ? <Link to="/home"> : <Link to="/">}`. It is still the same thing, but maybe constantlize the values in the Link component may make it work ?

Comment: Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help debug code we can't see.

Comment: I added some code hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You cannot change the link target after the click. The link was clicked the navigation action is dispatched at the same time the `submit` callback is called by clicking the button.

## Solution

Remove the `Link` and import the `useHistory` or `useNavigate` hook depending on `react-router-dom` version. When the submit handler is completing imperatively issue the redirect based on auth response.

```
// for react-router-dom@5
const history = useHistory();
// for react-router-dom@6
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const submit = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:2718/user/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(form),
     
      credentials: 'include',
    });
    if (res.status!==200){
      // for react-router-dom@5
      history.replace("/");
      // for react-router-dom@6
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    } else {
      // for react-router-dom@5
      history.replace("/home");
      // for react-router-dom@6
      navigate("/home", { replace: true });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // for react-router-dom@5
    history.replace("/");
    // for react-router-dom@6
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  }
};

...

<Button
  onClick={submit}
  variant="primary"
  size="lg"
  className="btn-lg"
  type="submit"
>
  Login
</Button>
```

Comment: Already tried that before posting, it had some issues related to the value of redirect not updating fast enough.
Any idea on how can I return from submit only after the state has updated?

Comment: @ItamarIvri Can you clarify what you mean by "value of redirect not updating fast enough"? What are you trying to do? Can you post a more complete and comprehensive code example, and clarify your use case and the issue you are facing? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I see you've also a button submitting a form. Is `submit` a `form` element's `onSubmit` handler? I don't see you preventing the default form action.

Comment: @ItamarIvri Are you just trying to conditionally redirect somewhere after the button/link has been clicked and the auth endpoint checked?

Comment: With your example, the state "redirect" is updated by setRedirect(), right? but states don't change immediately, they just enter a queue. so, the function submit finishes running before redirect's value is updated, and the <Link> doesn't work properly - because redirect still hasn't updated.

Comment: @ItamarIvri Ok, I see. Yeah, I think I understand what you are trying to do now.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to conditionally redirect after the login submit was called and returned an answer whether the login succeeded or not.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works. very appreciated